# Expo App Stuck on Splash Screen, No Errors

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, watchman

My app has been working fine but is now stuck on splash screen after building. I have been unable to understand why the issue is occurring. I tried to go back to a much older version of my project that I know was working, but it had the same issue.

I deleted node_modules and reinstalled on the old and new versions and they both had the same issue. So, I assumed it was a problem with my development environment. I had a friend clone the repo on his machine and test and he bizarrely got the exact same issue, which makes me think it isn't a problem with the dev environment. I reset my entire machine (MacBook Pro with Apple Silicon) and reinstalled homebrew, watchman, node, yarn, xcode, and expo-cli. Same issue.  I tried expo upgrade and expo doctor to try to resolve issues that way. I do not know what steps to take next. I am, however, getting some errors from watchman I will include below. Note this is an expo managed project.

**Build Logs: (after which app is frozen on home screen)**

```
chaserobbins@Chases-MacBook-Pro Handle-Customer-App % expo start -c
Starting project at /Users/chaserobbins/Documents/GitHub/Handle-Customer-App
Starting Metro Bundler
Your JavaScript transform cache is empty, rebuilding (this may take a minute).
▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄
█ ▄▄▄▄▄ █▄▀▀▄▄ ▀█ █ ▄▄▄▄▄ █
█ █   █ ███▄█  ▀▄▄█ █   █ █
█ █▄▄▄█ ██▄▀▄▀▀▀█▀█ █▄▄▄█ █
█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█ █ ▀▄▀▄▀ █▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█
█▄ ▀  ▀▄█▀ ▄▄▀▀█▀ █▄█▀█▀▀▄█
█▄▀▄▄█▀▄▄▀▀  ▀▄▄▄▀▀███▄▀▀ █
█▀▄▄█ ▄▄ ▀ █▄▄▀▄ █ ▄▀▀█▀ ██
█ ▄▀▄▀▀▄█▄██ ▄▄█ ▄▀ ██▄▀  █
█▄█▄▄▄▄▄█  ▀▀   █ ▄▄▄  ▄▀▄█
█ ▄▄▄▄▄ ██▀ ▄  ▄█ █▄█ ██▀ █
█ █   █ █ █▀▀▀██▄ ▄  ▄ █▀▀█
█ █▄▄▄█ █▀▀   █▄ ▄█▀▀▄█   █
█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█▄██▄██▄▄▄▄█▄▄███▄█

› Metro waiting on exp://192.168.0.107:19000
› Scan the QR code above with Expo Go (Android) or the Camera app (iOS)

› Press a │ open Android
› Press i │ open iOS simulator
› Press w │ open web

› Press r │ reload app
› Press m │ toggle menu

› Press ? │ show all commands

Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
watchman warning:  Recrawled this watch 27 times, most recently because:
MustScanSubDirs UserDroppedTo resolve, please review the information on
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#recrawl
To clear this warning, run:
`watchman watch-del '/Users/chaserobbins/Documents/GitHub/Handle-Customer-App' ; watchman watch-project '/Users/chaserobbins/Documents/GitHub/Handle-Customer-App'`

Recrawled this watch 27 times, most recently because:
MustScanSubDirs UserDroppedTo resolve, please review the information on
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#recrawl
To clear this warning, run:
`watchman watch-del '/Users/chaserobbins/Documents/GitHub/Handle-Customer-App' ; watchman watch-project '/Users/chaserobbins/Documents/GitHub/Handle-Customer-App'`

› Opening on iOS...
› Opening exp://192.168.0.107:19000 on iPhone 12
› Press ? │ show all commands
iOS Bundling complete 38112ms
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-native start",
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "web": "expo start --web",
        "eject": "expo eject"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
        "@expo/config-plugins": "5.0.0",
        "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
        "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.1.3",
        "@react-native-community/hooks": "^2.6.0",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
        "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.1.0",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.7",
        "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.2.3",
        "algoliasearch": "^4.10.5",
        "expo": "44.0.0",
        "expo-constants": "13.0.1",
        "expo-file-system": "13.1.4",
        "expo-firebase-recaptcha": "2.1.0",
        "expo-font": "10.0.4",
        "expo-haptics": "~11.1.0",
        "expo-image-picker": "12.0.1",
        "expo-linear-gradient": "11.0.3",
        "expo-linking": "3.0.0",
        "expo-notifications": "0.14.0",
        "expo-status-bar": "1.2.0",
        "expo-store-review": "5.1.0",
        "expo-updates": "0.11.7",
        "firebase": "8.2.3",
        "moti": "^0.18.0",
        "node-geometry-library": "^1.2.5",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-instantsearch-native": "^6.12.1",
        "react-native": "0.64.3",
        "react-native-confetti-cannon": "^1.5.2",
        "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.3.0",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.1.0",
        "react-native-maps": "0.29.4",
        "react-native-reanimated": "2.3.1",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
        "react-native-screens": "3.10.1",
        "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
        "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
        "react-native-webview": "11.15.0",
        "shorthash": "^0.0.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
        "eslint": "^8.11.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4"
    },
    "private": true,
    "name": "Handle-Customer-App",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "resolutions": { "react-native": "0.63.4" }

}
```

Any help or troubleshooting tips are much appreciated.

Comment: can you share your project?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by removing my "resolutions" line in my package.json. It seemed to be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had imports messed up and was creating an infinite loop on the entry page. I was loading App.js from App.js and trying to render it. Check your imports and make sure you're putting what you want into the JSX.